# Why the second derivative of a function cannot be greater (-2/x) times the first derivative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

I ran on this inequality while doing some modelling, and Wolfram alpha states it is False with no further explanation or input. I wonder if anyone can enlighten me on why it is always false.

I tried googling for methods for solving second order inequalities, but could not find any material that was easily understandable (at least at my biologist level of understanding). the only remotely connected subject I found was Grönwall's inequality on Wikipedia, but I can't see how it would help. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Inequality:

$$ \frac{d^2 f(x)}{d^2x} > -\frac{2}{x}*\frac{d f(x)}{dx}$$

Comment: This is impossible. For example taking $x=2$, it would mean that $y''(2) > -y'(2)$ which is false for most functions.

Comment: On the other hand, there are functions for which this inequality is true for every $x\ne 0$. Lets say, $f(x)=\frac{x^2 }{2}$, then we have $f''(x)=1$ and $\frac{-2}{x}\cdot x=-2$. I am pretty sure that Wolfram Alpha could not properly interprete this expression, at least it interpreted it not as desired.

Comment: Can you link to specifically what you were looking at in Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: Sure, [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=D%5By%2C%7Bx%2C2%7D%5D%3EDivide%5B%5C%2840%29-2D%5By%2Cx%5D%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D)

Comment: But nonetheless and @JeanMarie, if you could explain why $y''(2)>-y'(2)$ being false in most cases would be great. I'm still trying to understand the relationship between derivatives and may help with modelling. I had the impression they would be independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it's possible. If $f(x) = \exp(x)$ for $x >0. $

Comment: You are right. Shame, it would be really helpful for my research, hehe.

Comment: Not true for , for example , $x=-0.5$

Comment: I realized and edited it, thank you.